# Issue dealing with flex spaces

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to make a flex program that deletes all the spaces at the start and end of a line, and also translates multiple spaces to 1 space. This is the rules of the code I've come up with:

```
%% 
^[[:space:]]+ {}
[[:space:]]+$ {printf("\n");}
[[:space:]]+ {printf(" ");}
%%
```

To test this, I've been using notepad++ to check if the characters are changed correctly.
Notepad++ identifies line jumps as CR LF (I don't have knowledge about this words and their meaning), but after executing the second rule the result is that \n becomes LF and not CR LF, resulting in the following rule working unexpectedly.

Do you have any idea why this happens and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Aquí algo para leer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nueva_l%C3%ADnea). If you're using Mingw or some such, you'll end up using software compiled for Unix line endings on aa system where all the files have Windows line endings, which will lead to constant frustration. It's best that you at least make an effort to understand, independent of whether you use flex.

Comment: `\n` is LF is line feed. `\r` is CR is carriage return. The `$` is matching `\r\n` but you are only printing `\n`, so you are getting exactly what is to be expected.

Comment: @user207421: `$` matches (as trailing context) only the `\n`. The `\r` was matched by `[:space:]`.

Comment: @rici Surprising that. I worked on *flex* in the late 1980s, before it acquired `:space:`, both as user and contributor (all the 8-bit code is mine). Anyway the point remains that the OP is expecting `\r\n` but only printing `\n`, so the solution is in his hands.